# Installing driver, will it work with my system and is there any possibility of harm?

Tags: skype

I want to install this driver: [Click here for info about it](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R171789&SystemID=LATITUDE%20D620&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=8907&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=3&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=1&libid=3&fileid=235761)

I need the Stereo Mix function for skype calls so sound from my computer can be funneled to the call.

I am on an Inspiron 1520, which isn't listed on there.

Will this work? Are there any other ways to capture computer sounds and send them through skype?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Windows XP, Dell recommends the [following drivers](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WW1&catid=-1&dateid=-1&impid=-1&osl=EN&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=INS_PNT_PM_1520&hidos=WLH&hidlang=en&TabIndex=) for the Inspiron 1520:

Audio: SIGMATEL STAC 92XX C-Major HD Audio

5.10.0.5515_RC22-WHQL, A11

so it is definitely the correct driver.

Comment: Will the one you linked provide my computer the Stereo Mix option when using skype?

Comment: can you explain the problem in detail? you're using XP and Skype and the sound doesn't work?

Comment: I am in XP, and I really need to "send" the sounds that my computer makes through skype. I am looking into their .net api to see if I could program this myself, but skype's api is confusing...

Comment: so, you want to link the output of your soundcard (i.e. music) to the microphone?

Comment: Essentially, I was told stereo mix was the way to do it. I still want the output to come out of the speakers, just like, also send it through the call.

Comment: i'm not sure if there's a Stereo Mixer available for the SigmaTel soundcards (Realtek HD Audio cards do have it), did you install the driver via Setup or did you extract the driver and then installed it via the device manager? if you install the driver via the installer and there's no Mixer, then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I didn't try installing the driver yet. How do I check what my current driver is? I have sigmatel, but I dunno what kind?

Comment: you can find the version in the device manager. is this the original DELL installation? if there's no mixer, then it's unlikely you'll get one with a later driver.

Comment: This is the original installation. No mixer. Any way at ALL to do the same thing with Skype without it?

Comment: not that i know of, i'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I would go to the Dell support site and enter your service tag to be directed to the correct driver.  That should assure you get the right drivers.

From what I can see this is the right driver but may not be the latest version.

It will also usually tell you if the installer does not find supported hardware.

In addition, you sometimes need the HD Audio driver to get it all working.  Not sure on your Inspiron 1520 though

Answer (score 1):

If your computer isn't listed then there's a good chance it won't work. There may even be a slight chance it will make your system unstable - unlikely but it has to be mentioned.

However, it might "just work" - the only way you can know it by trying it.

If you are in any doubt don't install it.

If you want to take the risk then create a System Restore Point immediately before you do install so you can roll the OS back to a working state if it does cause problems.

Have you contacted Dell about a compatible driver?

Comment: No, I just found this driver a minute ago when someone told me to get "stereo mix" on this laptop. Any other ways?

Comment: As @DaveM suggests, enter your service tag - it should send you to the correct driver or tell you if there isn't one.

Comment: How can I find my service tag?

Comment: Service tag is on the bottom of the system.  White label with bar code and Express Servcie code (possibly)  Also available in the BIOS